# CSS Two divs with 100% width next to them not working on android

Tags: html, css

I have div0 div1 and div2

They are configured to so:

div0 has width: 200%
div1 is inside of div0 and has width: 50% (of div0)
div2 is inside of div0 and has width: 50 % (of div0)

On my computer it works well. Only one div is visible when loading the page. The second is next to it. I can see it when scrolling. But on my android phone it shows both divs and all smaller. So when loading the pge there is no invisible part of the page.

In example:

quizmaker.pythonanywhere.com/play/1

On Computer you have to wait 3 seconds.

On mobile device all is visible. How to solve that?

Comment: Its strange to use 200% then 100% Why not 100% then 50% ? However it could be due to your element try to set it a 49% and 49% (or 99,99 ofc)

Comment: I use 200% because the second div is then invisible until i scroll to the right of the page...

Comment: Have you forgot to say % in .continue you just said width: 50; is it normal ?

Comment: Oh... I fixed it. Let me try again...

Comment: It doesn't work on mobile device...

Comment: If the URL you provided is your source, you are missing some tags. (ex: doctype, html, head).

Comment: Also, as for mobile, you may need to take a look at the meta tag for setting the viewport.

Comment: Add the code snippet. Also verify did you added doctype in your root html file.

Comment: 1. Yeah - This is my site

Comment: 2. How do i specify viewport for this example?

Comment: No i did not add doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This should go in your `<head>`.

**Update**

Here is the source from the URL you linked, with the viewport (from above) included, along with some basic html fixes (added doctype, html, and head tags)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<style>
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
} 
#welcome{
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
}
#welcome:target{
    left: -100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s;
}

#welcome > .main{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
}
#welcome > .continue{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
}

/* #welcome > .main > .q {
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
} */

</style>
</head>
<body onload="timer=setTimeout(function(){ window.location='#welcome';}, 4000)">

<div id="welcome">
    <div class="main">
        <img class="q" src="/static/quiz.png" />
        <h2>ASapplications QuizMaker</h2>
        <br><h4>Faminator's quiz</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="continue"><h3>Please Wait...</h3></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YEAH!!! IT WORKED! SEE THE WEBSITE SWIPING FROM LEFT TO RIGHT - AWESOME. THANK YOU VERY MUCH ;)

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad I could help and thank you for accepting my answer. Happy coding.